# Dynamic Generate Copies of a Page in Google Forms

Tags: forms, google-forms

I'm looking to bulk input data from google forms. This involves 2 sections:

1. Initial Conditions
2. Observations

Everyone who wants to input data will be inputting 1 set of initial conditions, followed by somewhere between 5 and 20 (maybe more?) observations of multiple variables:

- Name
- Date
- Color
- Quantity
- Type

The problem is that I don't want to have to make people re-enter the initial conditions each time they submit a form.

Ideally they would be able to select a response after adding one observation:

- Add another observation
- Conclude session

**The thing I don't know how to do:** Add another observation would open a new *blank* observations page.

Anyone have any ideas about how to make the appropriate form?

Comment: Google Forms has an option to create a "PreFilled URL", which fills the Form with pre determined values.  The PreFilled URL can be obtained manually, or constructed with code.  There is no option to keep the form open after the user submits a response, so that the user can quickly start entering more data.  Ultimately, you might be better off creating your own input form with Apps Script HTML Service.  With that option, you could re-display the partially filled in form immediately after the submission.  If you don't have the time or skills to do that, just keep reopening the prefilled URL.

Comment: An interesting idea.

I'm hearing you say, instead of 1 form with lots of observations, 1 form whose "prefilled URL" is being constantly changed.

It doesn't sound promising, but I'm seeing shortcomings to the notion of bringing in multiple observations from one form anyways.

I'll look into Apps Script. Thanks